# Emails getting stuck in "messages with an unreachable destination queue" in Exchange

Tags: exchange-2003, queue, email

There's an exchange server with a problem that I'm trying to solve.  There's a couple hundred messages that have been sent out but need journaled.  They have been sent out but can't seem to make it to their journaling server.  I have verified that the server they need to get to is valid and that the data center hosting the server is not having any problems.  What are some other things I should look for to solve this issue?  If any more information is needed please feel free to ask.

Comment: What version of Exchange Server? Have you verified connectivity between the two server? Have you attempted to connect to the journaling server from the Exchange Server. What type of journaling?

Comment: Good questions.  It is Exchange 2003.  As far as the rest of your questions those in themselves would be good things for me to look into.  Except I'm fairly new to Exchange and don't know that much about it.  So how do I verify connection between Exchange and the Journaling server, or connect them.

Comment: Well that's a good question. Exchange 2003 doesn't have a "real" journaling function. It does allow you to archive all emails sent to and from a particular mailbox store to another mailbox, which I suppose could be a mailbox on another Exchange server in the organization. My first suggestion would be to see if the mailbox stores are configured to archive messages to another mailbox. If they are you can start your troubleshooting there. If they're not then a third party solution would appear to be in place and you'll have to hunt around for clues.

Comment: @joeqwerty offsite journal in exchange is done by creating a journal mailbox, a hidden custom recipient to an external email address, and setting the alternate recipient on the journal mailbox to the custom recipient.

Answer (score 1):

Your ISP may be blocking access to SMTP servers not operated by them. Test your connection to the journal server using these directions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123686.aspx

I ran in to this all the time at my last job where we had small offices with their own exchange servers journaling messages to us via SMTP and we required mutual tls encryption because of the sensitive nature of the email contents. The encryption made smart hosting impossible, so that ruled out the ISP's SMTP servers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the local message tracking for clues as to want may be taking place on the originating/last known processing system.